# A pattern matching against a constructor of an enum

Tags: rust

I have an enum:

```
pub enum Enum1 {
    A(String),
    B(i64),
    C(f64)
}
```

How can I do pattern matching against A? That is, I want to get its String value. I've tried this:

```
match optionMyEnum {
  Some(A(x: String)) => ...
```

and got plenty of the compile errors.

Comment: *match optionMyEnum* — note that Rust uses `snake_case` for variable names, not `camelCase`.

Answer (score 4):

[*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/) has an entire [section on matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/match.html). I'd **highly** encourage you to read that section (and the entire book). A lot of time and effort has gone into that documentation.

You simply specify a name to bind against. There's no need to write out types:

```
pub enum Enum {
    A(String),
    B(i64),
    C(f64),
}

fn main() {
    let val = Enum::A("hello".to_string());

    match val {
        Enum::A(x) => println!("{}", x),
        _ => println!("other"),
    }
}
```

In many cases, you will want to bind to a *reference* to the values:

```
Enum::A(ref x) => println!("{}", x),
```